# How to capture values in checked checkboxes using Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating a web application that will serve as a grocery store. The way I set it up is so the customer can come onto the website, click on the items that they would like to purchase, and then click a submit button to purchase those items. The problem I am running into is having a views.py function to take the information of which products were selected and subtracting 1 from the quantity of the database. When I say print(products) in my views.py, it returns "[]" in my terminal. This means that the values in my checked checkboxes are not being captured. Can anyone help me solve this?

```
"""models.py"""
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,default=1)
    Sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,default=1)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category',null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def inventory(request):
        products = request.POST.getlist('products')
        a = Post.objects.filter(title=products).update(
            quantity=F('quantity')-1
            )
        return redirect('blog-home')
```

urls.py

```
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('inventory', views.inventory, name='inventory'),
```

home.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.quantity > 0 %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="products" id="product_{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.id }}">
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.category }}</a>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
            <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
            Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
          </input>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% else %}
      <article class="media content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.category }}</a>
          </div>
          <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
          <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
          Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
          <p>Out Of Stock!</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="{% url 'inventory' %}"><button type="submit" name="Purchase" >Confirm Purchase</button></a>
{% endblock content %}
```

My goal is to click on the checkboxes, and when the customer clicks the button on the bottom of home.html, it triggers the inventory function to subtract "1" from the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a form in your HTML to handle this POST request.
Then handle this in your view with `if request.method == 'POST'` followed by the getlist() and the update function. also, i think you need to add a for loop to your queryset because there could be more than one product. hope this helps!

```
def inventory(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        products = request.POST.getlist('products')
        for product in products:
            a = Post.objects.filter(title=product).update(
                quantity=F('quantity')-1
            )
    return redirect('blog-home')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the problem is that I am getting nothing in my list. It returns an empty list, which means the values from the checkboxes are not being captured.